# populating google forms dropdowns with global contact directory

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-contacts-api

I am a total newbie when it comes to coding but have created a couple of google forms with some success.

The first question on my new form is "what is your name?" and I was hoping to get a box identical to the one in Gmail when you select a recipient and it auto-completes as you type - is it possible to do this in google forms by piggy backing off whatever code makes that work?

I couldn't work it out so in the meantime I have been trying to use a list item dropdown which looks up the contacts using google apps script.
So far, I have got it to create a question which populates the dropdown with 
84 instances of the word 'contact' (I have 84 contacts in my list!) but I cant work out how to actually get the names.

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var group = ContactsApp.getContacts();
var item = form.addListItem();
item.setTitle('What is your name?');
```

The above makes an array with 84 instances of the word contact.
So instead I tried this...

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var group = ContactsApp.getContacts();
for (var i in group) {
var now = (group[i].getFullName());
}
var item = form.addListItem();
 item.setTitle('What is your name?');
 item.setChoiceValues(now);
```

which still makes an array of 84 instances of contacts for var group, but also returns a string of one of my contacts for var now. Unfortunately item.setChoiceValues needs an array not a string.

In any case I'm not sure this is the right approach since this seems to be searching my personal contacts rather than the global directory on the domain. Is there a way to populate it with directory contacts without admin rights? (I have access to the contacts in Gmail so why not in Google Forms?)

I know its also possible to export a .csv from contacts to a sheet and populate from there but that won't be up to date unless I run a SIMS report daily (putting added strain on the system) and seems unnecessary when it clearly works in GMail already.

Like I said I am newbie and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a lot of questions here, so I'll help where I can.

A) I am unsure of the auto completion functions, this is mostly because I doubt google will let you piggy back off of their autocomplete.

B) You are so very close with your second approach. Just declare 'now' as a list and .push into it, like so:

```
//outside the for loop
var now = [];

for (i in group) {
  now.push(group[i]);
}
```

By the end of your for loop, you have a list 'now' populated with every member of group, in order.

C) I'm really not exactly sure what you're asking in this last question. You can access your gmail files, because you are guaranteed to be logged into google by virtue of accessing google forms. But I don't know that there is any other directory of contacts that it is possible to access, unless you make one yourself.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get each one of your peoples emails do

```
var email = group[i].getEmails()[0].getAddress;
```